# The set of sub sequential limits of a sequence is closed

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $\{P_n\}_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence in a metric spce $X$. Let $E$ denote the set of sub sequential limits of $\{P_n\}$. Show: $E$ is closed.

What I have tried:

Let $a$ be a limit point of $E$. We must show that $a$ is contained in $E$.

Let $\{e_n\}\rightarrow a$ where $\{e_n\}\subseteq E$. For all neighborhoods centered at $a$, there exists an element $e_i\in\{e_n\}$ in the neighborhood. Since neighborhoods are open, there is a subsequence $\{P_i\}$ approaching $e_i$ in the neighborhood. Thus, there exists some elements in $\{P_n\}_{n\geq1}$ approaching $a$, and since those are infinitely many elements, they form a subsequence of $\{P_n\}_{n\geq1}$. Therefore, $a$ is contained in $E$.

Is the proof correct? Is there a better wording for this proof? Thank you.

Comment: The existence of a sub sequence $P_i$ approaching to $e_i$ follows from the question (the definition of E) and not from the neighborhoods being open. also I'm not sure why there exists some element in $P_n$ approaching $a$.

Comment: so are you saying that take an element from each subsequence that are approaching $\{e_n\}$, and this new subsequence is a subsequence that converges to $a$, right?

Comment: What is ${P_i}$ a sub-sequence OF? .....And a neighborhood  of a is defined as a set $V$ such that there exists an open set $U$ with $p\in U\subset V.$.....  There is a member of the sequence ${e_n}$ in every open nbhd of $a$, but what does that have to do with the sequence ${P_i}$?

Comment: yes P. Rubin, but you don't just pick an element you need to take the elements such that the index is increasing..

Comment: Please state the problem in the body of your question.

Comment: @zhw. just did.

Comment: No, now the problem is stated nowhere! I'll edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof

I use your notations we have $e_n\rightarrow a$ and I'm going to construct a subsequence of $P_n$ converging to $a$.

first, pick $n_1$ such that $d(a,e_{n_1})<\frac{1}{2}$ then pick $m_1$ such that $d(P_{m_1}, e_{n_1})<1/2$ it follows by the triangle inequality that $d(a,P_{m_1})<1$.

Now by induction I claim there exists $m_k$ such that $m_k>m_{k-1}$,  and $d(a,P_{m_k})<1/k$.

Assume I already picked $m_1,...,m_k$ satisfying the condition we shall pick $m_{k+1}$ and this is how:

First we pick $n_{k+1}$ such that $d(a,e_{n_{k+1}})<1/2(k+1)$, then we have a sub sequence of $P_i$ converging to $e_{n_{k+1}}$ so we have arbitrary large values of $m_{k+1}$ (pick one larger than $m_{k}$) such that $d(e_{n_{k+1}},P_{m_{k+1}})<1/2(k+1)$
Use the triangle inequality and we are done.

Now the sequence $P_{m_k}$ is converging to $a$ and therefore $a\in E$.